# Android Studio Gradle Build Running slow

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build

When I start building project, sync or start app it always takes around 3 minutes on "Configure projects..." / "Gradle Build Running".
In Build Output it writes Executing tasks:[app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users... and for around 3 minutes its blank, and then the rest follows >Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE..... BUILD SUCCESFUL in 3m 19s.
I have feeling it started happening after I changed my laptop power mode to "Best battery life", but now its back to "Best performance" and its still slow.
I have tried many solutions that show on web but there is no difference. I think it is more connected with Android Studio settings or laptop settings then with Gradle Scripts.
Android Gradle Plugin Version is 8.1.2, and Gradle Version is 8.0.

I tried to add org.gradle.parallel=true and org.gradle.daemon=true in gradle.properties. I tried to reinstall whole Android Studio.